# Как правильно хранить данные из лога сервера в Redis

Tags: python, django, redis

Я работаю над парсером логов Apache. Парсинг выполняется скриптом на Python 3, размещенном в Django. Лог файл скачивается и парсится. Сейчас программа может сохранять распарсенные данные лога в моделях SQLite. Мне же надо сохранять в оперативной памяти, и потом делать статистику по параметрам записей. Я знаю, что Redis - это хранилище типа "ключ:значение". Как правильно писать данные в Redis, чтобы потом удобно было делать запросы для анализа по любому полю или по совокупности нескольких полей?

Answer (score 0):

- Для парсинга логов джанго не нужен, можно просто запускать скрипт питон из консоли и парсить логи.
- Не понятно для чего хранить данные в оперативке, логи могут быть большими и оперативки не хватит
- В БД как раз удобно анализировать данные и соединять таблицы по разным полям, как вы будете это делать в редис я не знаю

Comment: Django, потому что такое задание; я предположил, что надо делать используя кэширование, потому что жалко SSD, кроме того скорость обработки не помешает. Я не в курсе пока какой стэк лучше использовать для этого задания.

Comment: Оперативка дороже ssd. Бери обычное дисковое пространство и сохраняй все в БД

Comment: я так и сделал.